# Jetspeed imports in Java EE project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetspeed2

Can anybody please tell me what the following packages are and where I can get them?

```
import org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletContext;
import org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletRequest;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Apache portal project:

http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-1/

Download the JAR binaries and put them in your CLASSPATH.  All will be well, as long as the version in the JARs has the same signatures as your Java EE code.

I see a .zip file here:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/jetspeed/

Download it, extract it, and look inside the extracted files for the JARs you need.  Copy them into your project and it should be okay.

Comment: you mean the installer? because only the installer have JAR type